# Cannot use/import MySQLdb in ipython notebook (works well in ipython qtconsole)

Tags: python, ipython, mysql-python, jupyter-notebook

After great trouble with installing MySQLdb (due to incompatibility between 32-bit and 64-bit architectures) I have now run into another curious problem for which I cannot find the solution on the web.

`import MySQLdb` works fine in `ipython qtconsole` but not in `ipython notebook`. In the latter, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-dd22983d5391> in <module>()
----> 1 import MySQLdb

/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py in <module>()
     17 from MySQLdb.release import __version__, version_info, __author__
     18 
---> 19 import _mysql
     20 
     21 if version_info != _mysql.version_info:

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

`libmysqlclient.18.dylib` is in a directory which is in the `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

For example: `$echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` returns

```
:/usr/local/mysql/lib/:/usr/local/mysql/lib/
```

Any ideas how I can fix this, or whether this is `ipython notebook` bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but just in case anyone else is struggling with installing MySQLdb...

There is a pure python mysql driver called "pymysql".  You can usually use it as a drop in replacement for MySQLdb.  It's much easier to install because it doesn't require any binaries.

More details here: [What is PyMySQL and how does it differ from MySQLdb? Can it affect Django deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224807/what-actually-is-pymysql-and-how-it-differs-from-mysqldb-and-how-can-it-affect)