# Python 3.4.0 with MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, python-3.4

I have installed **Python version** **3.4.0** and I would like to do a project with MySQL database. I downloaded and tried installing **MySQLdb**, but it wasn't successful for this version of Python.

Any suggestions how could I fix this problem and install it properly?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

MySQLdb does not support Python 3 but it is not the only MySQL driver for Python.

[mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) is essentially just a fork of MySQLdb with Python 3 support merged in (and a few other improvements).

[PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) is a pure python MySQL driver, which means it is slower, but it does not require a compiled C component or MySQL libraries and header files to be installed on client machines. It has Python 3 support.

Another option is simply to use another database system like [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org).

Comment: I tried also with pymysql but still nothing. I will try with git repo and see if I can get it to work, otherwise I am just going to re-install 3.4 and install 2.7 version...

Comment: Can you be more specific about what went wrong with pymysql?

Comment: I actually just got it to work, I had some problems with pip installer tool, that's why I wasn't able to install anything but I fixed it, MySQLdb is still not working even though I installed it properly this time, but then and I ran **pip install PyMySQL** and it's all working good with PyMySQL my code is showing everthing from my MySQL database, thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: Great, glad that worked out!  If you are having trouble with `pip` I recommend looking into using a `virtualenv` and running all pip commands inside the `virtualenv` as a user (not as root/with `sudo`)

Comment: Andrew could you please give me your e-mail so I can contact you in order to get some advises about pymysql, because I want to learn it little bit more, for example I would like to use it with Flask but I am not really sure how to do it so if you could help, if you know it?

Comment: I can be reached at firstname.lastname@gmail, but I'm no expert on flask specifically. I do know that flask uses an ORM called SQLAlchemy, which is much much nicer than bare SQL.  So I'd recommend starting with the flask database documentation and using the SQLAlchemy pymysql connector for that.

Comment: still have django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Comment: @madzohan Django documentation now recommends you use mysqlclient as the primary MySQL database driver. Try installing that instead and see if it works. If it doesn't (perhaps because your version of Django is old?), or if you want to use pymysql anyways, refer to the second answer on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224807/what-is-pymysql-and-how-does-it-differ-from-mysqldb-can-it-affect-django-deploy

Comment: @AndrewGorcester `it is not the only MySQL driver for Python` You are right, so for completeness your answer really should mention [Oracle's MySQL/Python connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) which is really well documented, as well as any pros and cons you perceive for that adapter to help future readers weigh pros and cons. The answer ranks high on Google so that investment would be worthwhile it for the community. Thanks!

Comment: To use *mysqlclient* in Python 3 and above in your python code add at the top *import MySQLdb* It was not that obvious for me.

Answer (score 22):

Use [mysql-connector-python](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/). I prefer to install it with pip from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python):

```
pip install --allow-external mysql-connector-python mysql-connector-python
```

Have a look at its [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) and [examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-examples.html).

If you are going to use pooling make sure your database has enough connections available
as the default settings may not be enough.

Comment: For anyone who is not aware, this is the adapter made by Oracle (which now owns MySQL), so it should be pretty "close to the database". It works with 3.4, has great documentation, and provides a number of useful methods and attributes not found in PEP249. (Is that a good thing? It depends on whether you care about extracting the most juice out of your database, or on whether you want to stay close to PEP249 to make it easy to switch databases later.) They have announced a C version (2.1) but haven't said when it will be out.

Comment: zx81 one bonus with mysql-connector-python is no dependencies and doesn't require mysql or mysql-client to be installed which is handy for keeping installs small

Comment: I can't install it with `pip`... *No distributions at all found for mysql-connector-python*.

Comment: Try pip install --allow-external mysql-connector mysql-connector       source code for it is at https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work anymore, at least using pip 8.1.2 on python 3.5. I get this error `DEPRECATION: --allow-external has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Due to changes in the repository protocol, it no longer has any effect.`

Comment: yes no longer works.  I don't know a replacement as haven't worked with mysql this year only postgresql/redshift.

Comment: alternative installation methods https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-python/8.0/installation.html

Answer (score 10):

Install pip:

```
apt-get install pip
```

For acess MySQL from Python, install:

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Comment: how to import this module?

Answer (score 4):

There is a Ubuntu solution available either through the Ubuntu Software Center or through the Synaptic Package Manager. This will connect Python version 3.4.0  to MySQL. Download "*python3-mysql.connector*" version 1.1.6-1.

Note that the connection syntax does **not** use "**MySQLdb**". 
Instead read: [Connecting to MySQL Using Connector/Python](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html)

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
sudo pip3 install mysqlclient
```

that worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

I solved it this way:
download the zipped package from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python) and follow this set of instructions:

```
unzip  /path/to/downloads/folder/mysql-connector-python-VER.zip
```

In case u got a `.gz` u can use ->

```
tar xzf mysql-connector-python-VER.tar.gz
```

And then:

```
cd mysql-connector-python-VER  # move into the directory

sudo python3 setup.py install # NOTICE I USED PYTHON3 INSTEAD OF PYTHON
```

You can read about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation-source.html)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that at the moment Ubuntu 15.10 has a but with python3 and pip3.

As elaborated in [this article](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3u1eek/after_installing_with_pip3_python3_cannot_find/).

The problem makes pip3 install to python3.5 while python3 is actually running python3.4 :(

Until a proper solution will be available via the updates you can do one of the following:

run

```
python3 -m pip install pymysql
```

instead of

```
pip3 install pymysql
```

(or any other package)

Now

```
import pymysql
```

should work in python3 and in idle3.

Alternatively, if you explicitly need 3.5 you can use explicit python3.5 instead of python3. but idle3 will still point to 3.4...

Comment: I used "python -m pip install pymysql" instead of " python3 -m pip install pymysql " !

Answer (score 1):

[mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) is a fork of MySQLdb and can serve as a drop-in replacement with Python 3.4 support. If you have trouble building it on Windows, you can download it from [Christoph Gohlke's Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) or [oursql](https://launchpad.net/oursql/py3k). For *oursql*, use the *oursql py3k series* as my link points to.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a work around and try something like:

```
import datetime
#import mysql
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = '127.0.0.1',user = 'someUser', passwd = 'foobar',db = 'foobardb')
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: just kidding wt creds ;)

Comment: yeah, I know people here are way too serious haha

Answer (score -1):

for fedora and python3 use: dnf install mysql-connector-python3