# Python 3.4 MySQL connection

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.4

I want my Python code to connect to my SQL server. Everything I find on Google is for Python 3.2 or older. Is there any possibility that I can connect to a MySQL server without installing anything? And if not, is there something compatible with Python 3.4?

Comment: Have you tried the code geared towards 3.2 with 3.4? It will probably work fine.

Comment: @Wooble I don't like to be a douche but if that are the rules then I'll try to follow them

Comment: There is no way to connect to MySQL in any version of Python without installing anything.

Comment: @dano I just tried oursql and it didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [mysql connector python](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)  or you can install it from pip from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python)

See the reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376103/python-3-4-0-with-mysql-database)