# MySQLdb with python3.4

Tags: python, mysql-python, python-3.4

I am using python 3.4 on Lubuntu, which has by default both python2.7 and python3.4

I installed MySQLdb and am trying to use it in python3.4 using pip3

But merely import MySQLdb results in this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tahseen/workspace/stockproject/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as mysql
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql

ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/_mysql.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct`
```

Surprisingly when I use python2.7, this error does not come up

Answer (score 3):

Quoting another post:

> "MySQLdb does not support Python 3 but it is not the only MySQL driver
>   for Python.
>
> You can try using PyMySQL. It is a pure python MySQL driver, which
>   means it is slower, but it does not require a compiled C component or
>   MySQL libraries and header files to be installed on client machines.
>   The latest version on pypi, 0.6.2, has Python 3.4 support.
>
> Another option is simply to use another database system like
>   PostgreSQL."

link: [Python 3.4.0 with MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376103/python-3-4-0-with-mysql-database)

ps. if you chek at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.3 you'll be able to read that Python 3.0 will be supported in a future release

Comment: `MySQL-python` has been claiming it will support Py3 in a future release for years without doing so. If you want an API equivalent replacement for Py3, [take a look at `mysqlclient`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient), which forked `MySQL-python`, adding support for Py3.3+ (while still supporting 2.7 as well, so you can use it as a replacement for `MySQL-python` on both Py2 and Py3). Unlike `PyMySQL` (and like `MySQL-python`), it's a Python extension module, so the performance is equivalent (read: faster, and potentially _much_ faster for threading since it can release the GIL).

Comment: It's 2020 and it still doesn't support python3. Apparently the project has been abandoned _many_ years ago.