# Unhandled exception in thread started python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

Recently I installed Python 3.4.3 in my environment (Windows 8.1) and tried to deploy a simple Django server. When I runned the command `python manage.py runserver` but the following exceptions appeared:

> Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x031B5D68>

I believe this exception happened due some error or misconception when I tried to install `mysql-python`. I changed the `DATABASE` config in `settings.py` from "django.db.backends.mysql" to "django.db.backends.sqlite3" and runned pretty well. The configs that I tried are the following:

```
# Defective configuration
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'test',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'doideira',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '3306',
  } 
}
```

But using SQLite works:

```
# With SQLite 3 works
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
     'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
  }
}
```

I am experiencing some troubles and any advice would be appreciated. I would like to know why this is happening and how can I workaround it.

Further info:

- Mysql version is 5.6.4
- Mysql Python version is 1.2.5
- Python version is 1.2.5
- Windows 8.1
- Django version is 1.8.1

The full log error can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/9L79dCUA).

**Update** *Saturday 16, May 2015*:

I came up with an simple solution: downgrade Python from 3.x to 2.7.x. I explain the steps below as [the answer of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280316/3147039). I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23376193/3147039) very useful, but now that I'm using Python 2.7 everything is ok.

I also found this article that answers the question "[Should I use Python 2 or Python 3 for my development activity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3)" and that was what made me to decide whether keep with Python3 or Python2. Since Python3 hasn't a strong library support, I will wait a little more until update it.

Comment: I believe Mysql Python is not compatible with python 3.x yet. Check documentation here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5

Comment: That's right @nikhiln. It seems that Python 3.x is not supported yet. I just need to downgrade Python a little bit and run some scripts. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka! I figured out the answer guys.

As @nikhiln mentioned in the comments, mysql-python is not supported yet for Python 3.x:

> MySQL-3.23 through 5.5 and Python-2.4 through 2.7 are currently supported. Python-3.0 will be supported in a future release. PyPy is supported.
>   [mysql-python 1.2.5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5)

To work around it, I downgraded my Python from 3.4 to 2.7.9, and installed the [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) and [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092) to properly run it.

Then I installed the mysql-python client using a *.whl* file from [Christoph Gohlke`s Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python). I did as following (assuming C++ 2008, Compiler for Python and [Pip](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/) are already installed):

1. `pip install wheel` to install the wheel program. With it you are able to compile *.whl* files.
2. Download the properly file *MySQL_python‑1.2.5‑cp27‑none‑...*
3. Run the command `pip install MySQL_python‑1.2.5‑cp27‑none‑...whl` (the file you downloaded in the previous step).

And *Voilà*! mysql-python is running swiftly now!
To check if everything is ok, just run `import MySQLdb` into Python shell.

```
>>> import MySQLdb
```

If no exception was raised, then the work is done.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3 we need to install mysqlclient and PyMySQL