# installation error of mysql for django 1.8

Tags: mysql, django, windows, python-3.x, mysql-python

i'm trying to install mysql using pip and this error appears.
I'm new to python

the cmd says

```
"fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h: no such file or directory 
error: command 'C:\\programfiles(x86)\\microsoft visual studio 10.0\\vc\\bin\\c1.exe' 
failed to exit status 2"
```

if it is already solved i am sorry because i don't understand the presented solutions such as [site.cfg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972259/cannot-open-include-file-config-win-h-no-such-file-or-directory-while-inst) that they say don't work anymore (i don't even understand it) my problem is also similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773732/compilation-error-in-visual-studio-linked-with-python26)

I'm using python 3.4.3 and django 1.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql-python is currently not supported by python 3
You have to install mysqlclient and PyMysql

Comment: hhmm yeah i was planning to move to 2.x
anyway tnx

Comment: so i installed 2.x with the same problem dunno why

Comment: Is same error coming in python 2.x for python-mysql ?

Comment: Try the answer from this question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228874/unhandled-exception-in-thread-started-python-manage-py-runserver/30230980#30230980

Comment: i moved to python 2.7 with the same problem but it's solved now
(pip did not work but downloading an exe of mysql-python, executing it did the trick)

1st moving the connector from program files to program files(x86) then executing the mysql-python