# Raspberry Pi python 3 - "No module named 'MySQLdb'"

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, raspberry-pi3

I'm playing with my first Raspberry Pi 3 project, and I've hit a snag. I've found some example code which uses MySQL `import MySQLdb as mdb`, but when I try to run the code I get a 'No module named 'MySQLdb''...

I've been googling for ages now, and I'm getting no where. Here's a few of the options I've tried:

- `pip install mysql-python`
- `sudo pip install mysql-python`
- `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`
- `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865270/how-to-install-python-mysqldb-module-using-pip), try:

```
apt-get install python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
pip install MySQL-python
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, As above, I've tried both of those (in order), and it hasn't solved the problem.
One thing that occurred to me last night was that I was using Python 3.4, and I read some old posts that said MySQLdb wasn't available for Python 3... Is this still the case? Do I need to use Python 2, or is there another way?

Comment: Ah okay. I thought maybe you'd tried to install `libmysqlclient-dev` *after* `mysql-python`. Based on what you said, I looked around and found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376103/python-3-4-0-with-mysql-database. `mysql-python` does *not* work with Python 3.4, but that post offers several alternatives. Hopefully those help!