# Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Tags: python, mysql, django, visual-c++

** Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279**

I am getting this error when i am installing mysqlclient or mysql-python

by pip install mysqlclient

i have updated everything and not using any of the visual studio produsct using sublime text  please help me !

Comment: Have you installed the sdk from the link?

Comment: no it is for windows 7 but i have windows 10

Comment: It doesn't matter. Most likely, _mysqlclient_ (or one of its dependencies?) doesn't come with binaries, but rather it's built from (_C_) sources at `pip install` time. In order to build _C_ code, you need a compiler. _Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0_ is the one used to build this module. It comes with _Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1_ (regardless of the (__newer__) _Win_ version that you're on).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to test whether what I've stated in the comment is true, so I attempted `pip install`ing *MySQLClient* in one of my *Python 2.7.13* (*VEnv*) installations:

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py2713x64-test>Scripts\pip.exe install -v mysqlclient
> Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
> Config variable 'WITH_PYMALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
> Config variable 'Py_UNICODE_SIZE' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect
> Collecting mysqlclient
>   1 location(s) to search for versions of mysqlclient:
>   * https://pypi.python.org/simple/mysqlclient/
>   Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/mysqlclient/
>   Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/mysqlclient/" in the cache
>   No cache entry available
>   Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
>   "GET /simple/mysqlclient/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2671
>   Updating cache with response from 
>   "https://pypi.python.org/simple/mysqlclient/"
>   Caching b/c date exists and max-age > 0
>   Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/mysqlclient/
>
>   # @TODO - cfati: Truncated output
>
>   No cache entry available
>   "GET /packages/40/9b/0bc869f290b8f49a99b8d97927f57126a5d1befcf8bac92c60dc855f2523/mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz HTTP/1.1" 200 82102
>   Downloading mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz (82kB)
>   Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/40/9b/0bc869f290b8f49a99b8d97927f57126a5d1befcf8bac92c60dc855f2523/mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz#md5=e7fb95c4055e2d8a3322db5c85ab6fc8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/mysqlclient/)
>     99% |############################### | 81kB 252kB/s eta 0:00:01  Updating cache with response from "https://pypi.python.org/packages/40/9b/0bc869f290b8f49a99b8d97927f57126a5d1befcf8bac92c60dc855f2523/mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz"
>
>   # @TODO - cfati: Truncated output
>
>   running build_ext
>   building '_mysql' extension
>   error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
> error
>   Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
> ```

What is happening:

- It connects to [[PyPI]: Links for mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/simple/mysqlclient)
- It checks the latest version: ***v1.3.10*** (at answer time)
- Since this version is only compiled for *Python 3.5* and *Python 3.6* (*064bit* / *032bit*):

  - *mysqlclient-1.3.10-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl*
  - *mysqlclient-1.3.10-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl*
  - *mysqlclient-1.3.10-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl*
  - *mysqlclient-1.3.10-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl*
- It downloads the source archive: *mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz*
- The archive contains (besides the *Python* files, installation files and other additional files) a file: *_mysql.c*, which is the backend for communicating to *MySQL*. As I stated, in order to use the *C* code, it has to be compiled into a *.dll* (*_mysql.pyd*). For more info on building (compiling) *C* code, check [[SO]: LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777349/4788546)
- Now, since the *.dll* will be loaded by *Python* when importing *MySQLClient*, it has to be compiled with the same compiler, or better: it must use the same *C Runtime Library* (***UCRT***) that *Python* ([[Python.Wiki]: WindowsCompilers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers)) uses (well it's not really a must, but using more than one *UCRT* in a process, is a recipe for disaster in 99.99% cases), it tries to build it with *Microsoft Visual C++ **9**.0* (or *VStudio 2008*), but it doesn't find it, and hence the error

The only thing that differs in your case it's the *Microsoft Visual C++ **10**.0* (or *VStudio 2010*) version, which tells me that you're using *Python 3.3* or (most likely) *Python 3.4*.

Possible solutions:

- Download *Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1* from the provided link and install it (then rerun the `pip install mysqlclient` command). It's a one time step, and I'm 100% positive that you'll need it when you'll have to install other 3<sup>rd</sup>-party modules that will come with *C* sources.
  More details: [[SO]: Visual Studio NMake build fails with: fatal error U1052: file 'win32.mak' not found (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73167842/4788546)
- Download and install a newer *Python* version (*3.5*, *3.6*) and run their *pip* as the package is already compiled for these versions
- *Google* for other places where you could download the compiled version of the module for your *Python* version. Although you should be careful when installing stuff from untrusted sources
- [[SO]: Python 3.4.0 with MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23376103/4788546) mentions another package: [[GitHub]: PyMySQL/PyMySQL - Pure Python MySQL Client](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) (other packages are listed there as well), I'm not sure how similar the 2 are, but you could give it a shot

Comment: Did this answer your question?