# How to install MySQLdb with Anaconda on Mac

Tags: python, mysql-python, anaconda

I have the anaconda distribution with python version 2.7. I tried several commands such as sudo and pip but nothing seems to work. I am told in the shell that the installation is complete but every time i try to send in the console "import MySQLdb" i get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    import MySQLdb

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 19, in

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in

File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in **bootstrap**

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/andreasportelli/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/andreasportelli/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found

What should I do to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [pymysql](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL)
You can install it by

```
conda install pymysql
```

FYI [What is PyMySQL and how does it differ from MySQLdb? Can it affect Django deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224807/what-is-pymysql-and-how-does-it-differ-from-mysqldb-can-it-affect-django-deploy)